# Inline MS Build Task in separate AppDomain

Tags: reflection, msbuild, appdomain, msbuild-task

**End Goal:**

I would like to have a custom build task that takes my compiled assembly, and extracts all instances of a particular attribute for automated documentation and uninstallation. (In this case the GUID attribute for a set of COM-visible types).

**Problem:**

After reading some examples, the prospect of using an [Inline Build Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx)  was rather tempting. However, my task needs to reflect across the built assemblies and extract certain meta-data from it (specifically attributes).

The catch is reflecting over the assembly will lock the output file until the AppDomain is unloaded, which in this case appears to be only when Visual Studio is closed. The result: the build can only once per session.

I see that there exists special build task classes, namely `AppDomainIsolatedTask` but I can find no examples or evidence that this class can be utilized for an inline task.

**Question:**

Is it possible to run an Inline Build task in a separate AppDomain? If so, then how?

**Code Sample:** (as short as possible)

```
<UsingTask TaskName="InDomainTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
<Task><Code Type="Class" Language="cs"><![CDATA[

    public class InDomainTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Log.LogMessage("InDomainTask AppDomain.Id = " + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id);
            return true;
        }
    }

]]></Code></Task>
</UsingTask>
<UsingTask TaskName="OutDomainTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
<Task><Code Type="Class" Language="cs"><![CDATA[

    [Microsoft.Build.Framework.LoadInSeparateAppDomain]
    public class OutDomainTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.AppDomainIsolatedTask
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Log.LogMessage("OutDomainTask AppDomain.Id = " + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id);
            return true;
        }
    }

]]></Code></Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="Compile">
  <InDomainTask />
  <OutDomainTask />
</Target>
```

The build output of these is:

```
1>  InDomainTask AppDomain.Id = 1
1>  OutDomainTask AppDomain.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

Inline tasks use the `CodeTaskFactory` to create the task, and if you [take a look at the code on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/451b53816ed45d01fc2c96e779977083e234fdfb/src/XMakeTasks/CodeTaskFactory.cs#L329), you will see that after compiling an assembly that contains the code, an instance of the task is creating using `Activator.CreateInstance`. This means it is always created in the same AppDomain as MSBuild.

Compare that to [pre-compiled tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/451b53816ed45d01fc2c96e779977083e234fdfb/src/XMakeBuildEngine/Instance/TaskFactories/AssemblyTaskFactory.cs#L375), which use the [`TaskLoader`](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/2db4d4b6821ff65987b2843d29cc5f02c4db59f5/src/Shared/TaskLoader.cs#L45) class to create an instance of the task, and that `TaskLoader` looks for the `LoadInSeparateAppDomainAttribute` on the task type and creates an instance in a separate AppDomain if it's found.

The easiest solution is to turn your inline code into a pre-compiled task. It's really easy to do:

1. Create a class library project
2. Reference `Microsoft.Build.Utilities`.
3. Create a class for your task.
4. Compile the project.
5. Replace your `UsingTask` element with one that specifies the assembly that contains the tasks.

Here's an example:

Your class library that contains the tasks:

```
public class InDomainTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogMessage(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public class OutDomainTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.AppDomainIsolatedTask
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogMessage(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your MSBuild file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="InDomainTask" AssemblyFile="path\to\the\class\library.dll"/>
<UsingTask TaskName="OutDomainTask" AssemblyFile="path\to\the\class\library.dll"/>

<Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="Compile">
  <InDomainTask/>
  <OutDomainTask/>
</Target>
```

This outputs:

```
MSBuild.exe
taskAppDomain (in-proc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can run your job in separate MsBuild.exe process using `Exec` command and pass in same current targets file and needed properties.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="RunCodeFromTargetPath" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeFromTargetPathAfterTargets>PrepareForRun</RunCodeFromTargetPathAfterTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="RunCodeFromTargetPath" AfterTargets="$(RunCodeFromTargetPathAfterTargets)">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64'">
      <MsBuildFolderLocation >\amd64</MsBuildFolderLocation><!--support for x64 only assemblies -->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)$(MsBuildFolderLocation)\MSBuild.exe&quot; /target:RunCodeFromTargetPathInternal /p:TargetPath=&quot;$(TargetPath.Replace('\','\\'))&quot; &quot;$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="RunCodeFromTargetPathInternal">
    <RunCodeFromTargetPathTask />
  </Target>
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="RunCodeFromTargetPathTask"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="$(TargetPath)" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          // your code here
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
</Project>
```